# Preserving text when opening csv files with Excel

Tags: csv, format

I have a CSV file to examine.  By default it opens with Microsoft Excel.  There are a couple fields which I am having problems with.  One is a case number (like 1413212331, all digits).  Another is a date such as 07/04/2020.

Excel is displaying the case numbers as something like 1.413e+9, and the date as 7/4/2020.  I really need to see them in their original format.

I selected the column with the case number and did a format cells - text but it kept the value as it is.
And I can't really format the date columns as a specific format, as some might be like 7/4/2020 and some as 07/04/2020.

So is there some other app to look at a CSV file with (other than word/notepad which does not do the lines very well)?  Or a way to open a CSV file with Excel and have it treat everything as actual text as it is in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Libre Office Calc could work. I created a .csv file to test it just with the 2 following lines (tabulation seperated):

```
05/04/2020    15545789
03/04/2020    78954566
```

And I opened it with Libre Office Calc (specifying tabulation separation) and kept the right format for the number and date.

But I think that if Excel read your `1413212331` as `1.413e+9` and that cell format does not allow you to see all digits, it might be because your csv file is not formatted as you think. So what is the format of your data in the csv file ? Maybe you could show an example with a copy/paste of a line

Comment: I will do my best.  Have to avoid company proprietary stuff:  But CSV files should all be plain text, no?

Comment: Sorry, there is too much confidential data.  I did look at it with wordpad to verify, but wordpad is just too bulky, and things spill over into new lines.  Here is part of a line: 11.62,0,0,0,0,0,11.62,05/03/2010

Comment: Yes sure no problem ! Just the format of a part of line is perfect !
So you want to read this line as 7 numbers and a date i guess (with virgule separation) ?! If you use Libre Office Calc to open it, it will open a window where you will have to specify "virgule" separation and it should work as you want.

Comment: I'll try to see what happen with Excel when I'm home with my personal laptop but I think that it's just about the number format. It seems that Excel show you a exponential/scientific format for the number while you want it to be a number format with decimals.